# compile mysql driver for qt5.12 from source on centos 7

Tags: qt, mariadb

I am trying to compile qt and qt mysql driver using https://wiki.qt.io/Building_Qt_5_from_Git article
I have a mariadb 10.4, installed from official repo, also have a devel package

```
MariaDB-client-10.4.8-1.el7.centos.x86_64
MariaDB-devel-10.4.8-1.el7.centos.x86_64
MariaDB-compat-10.4.8-1.el7.centos.x86_64
MariaDB-common-10.4.8-1.el7.centos.x86_64
MariaDB-server-10.4.8-1.el7.centos.x86_64
```

When I configure make file it doesn't show mysql driver

```
./configure -developer-build -opensource -confirm-license -nomake examples -nomake tests -prefix /opt/qt/qtbase-5.12
```

```
Qt Sql Drivers:
  DB2 (IBM) .............................. no
  InterBase .............................. no
  MySql .................................. no
  OCI (Oracle) ........................... no
  ODBC ................................... no
  PostgreSQL ............................. no
  SQLite2 ................................ no
  SQLite ................................. yes
    Using system provided SQLite ......... no
  TDS (Sybase) ........................... no
```

Also after compile tried to compile driver manually, but got an error

```
Project ERROR: Library 'mysql' is not defined.
```

Answer (score 0):

You should add `-sql-mysql` to your configure arguments.
Do not forget to [clean](https://wiki.qt.io/Building_Qt_5_from_Git#Cleaning) your Qt directory before reconfigure by running:

```
git submodule foreach --recursive "git clean -dfx" && git clean -dfx
```